# SCSS Variables not loading across files

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I have a folder with all my .scss files that I want to compile into .css files using gulp. My gulpfile.js looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass',
            function (){
              return gulp.src('css/modules/*.scss')
              .pipe(sass())
              .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
            }
);
```

When I run the gulp sass command, I get the error that a variable ($med-green) is not defined in blocks.scss.  It is defined in base.scss, which gets compiled first because it compiled in alphabetical order (and I do end up with a base.css file). The main.scss file is in the css directory and all the other files are in the css/modules directory, so I know the paths are correct.  The   How do I get the variables to be visible to all the .scss files? What am I missing?

I also have a main.scss file that imports all my .scss files.  If I could use that to compile them into 1 .css file (which is the ultimate goal), then that would be great. When I try to do that, I get the error "Error: File not found with singular glob".  The main.scss file looks like this, where modules is a subfolder of css, where my main.scss file is.

```
@import "./modules/_reset.scss";
@import "./modules/_base.scss";
@import "./modules/_header.scss";
@import "./modules/_footer.scss";
@import "./modules/_blocks.scss";
@import "./modules/_interviews.scss";
@import "./modules/_search.scss";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case, there is two things to tell >>>

first: to solve your problem, you need to compile only one file (main.scss) that already imports all other scss files

second: scss files starting with ( _ ), get ignored when compiling in gulp-sass,
it is like telling the gulp-sass compiler that these files are for import only.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
return gulp.src('css/main.scss')
```

in your `sass` task.  You don't want individual css files for each of your `modules/*.scss` files, that is the point of partials and imports - you just want the one, `main.scss`, which imports them all.  Individually, one file will not see the other's variables because each of them do not import all the others.

You want just `main.css` at the end to include in your html file.